# How to identify binary files in nodejs with a .js extension?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following files in my folder :

[image]

Now most of these are JS files and if you can see there are a bunch of files that start with a `.` , and are slightly faded , these files also have a `.js` extension. If i open any of these files in a text editor i see the following:

[image]

As you can see the message says the file cannot be open as it may be very large or a binary file (i doubt it's because its very large file because when i opened this file in the browser , all i see is a bunch of special characters, don't seem like a JS file at all .. see below).

Below is what i see when i open the JS file in a browser:

Now in my express app , i have a few lines of code that basically beautifies a file if it has a .js extension , the code looks like so:

[image]

```
data = fs.readFileSync( path_Url , 'utf8', ),
js_beautified_content = beautify( data, { indent_size: 2, space_in_empty_paren: true });

console.log( 'PATH URL IS ' + path_Url );

fs.writeFileSync( path_Url , js_beautified_content , 'utf8');

data = fs.readFileSync( path_Url , 'utf-8' );
```

Now ofcourse the above code is inside a forEach loop and its all Syncronious , but when the for loop runs into one of these binary files , my app throws an error, like so:

> { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open
>   'C:\Users\gautam.fonseca\Desktop\isales_to_veeva_V1\VEEVA_CONVERTED\converted_to_
>   veeva\demo_EZE_MIX_One_Step_Target01\assets\js._jquery.mobile-1.2.0.2.js'
>       at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:646:18)
>       at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:1291:33)
>       at replaceContaint (C:\Users\gautam.fonseca\Desktop\isales_to_veeva_V1\isales_to_veeva_V1\routes\index.js:305:20)
>       at C:\Users\gautam.fonseca\Desktop\isales_to_veeva_V1\isales_to_veeva_V1\routes\index.js:273:13
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at isalesToVeevaSanitization (C:\Users\gautam.fonseca\Desktop\isales_to_veeva_V1\isales_to_veeva_V1\routes\index.js:257:11)
>
> ```
> at C:\Users\gautam.fonseca\Desktop\isales_to_veeva_V1\isales_to_veeva_V1\routes\index.js:271:13
> ```

How can i circumvent this ? What do i do when i run into one of these binary files and identify them ?

**P.S.** currently i am considering wrapping my code inside a try catch block , but i would prefer if i could get a solution that identifies such files that can't be read or rather binary files that can't be read. I am not sure if try catch is a better solution though , so i am open to an answer that accomodates that solution too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a file is binary or ASCII with Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225399/check-if-a-file-is-binary-or-ascii-with-node-js)

Comment: I'm not a windows user, but what makes you think those files are anything other than some os system metadata file (as opposed to one your application actually uses)?