# Decode binary of image to base64

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am making https get a request to get the image and trying to show that image into the desktop app, but I am getting a weird binary response of the image, like diamonds, symbols etc. But I am unable to convert that to base64, but if I give absolute path of the image into the image src tag then it renders fine, but this has an issue with the server authentication process, so I need to make https call and show the image. I have attached the response of the image, can anyone help me how to decode this string and show the image in JavaScript?

[image: Text containing all weird symbols, starting with "???? ?JIFF"]

Code to decode: angular ajax, response type is set as "binary"

```
const length = response.length;
const array = new Uint8Array(length);
for (let i = 0; i < length; i++){
    array[i] = response.charCodeAt(i);
}
const u8 = new Uint8Array(array);
const b64encoded = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, u8));
```

Comment: Can you show the code you use to download the binary blob, and the code you tried using to convert it to a Base64 url? It allows us to build our answer on knowledge you already have, and in turn makes it easier to understand for you. Thanks

Comment: for now what I did is, I changed the responseType parameter value to "blob", from there I converted to "URL.createObjectURL(blob)" which worked, but now problem is, it also returns blob for base64 encoded response string, now i have the challenge to handle base64 & binary response for the same https get request

Comment: Are you able to use the new `fetch` api? When you use fetch, you first get a "response" object that contains all headers and the status code, and you can basically add an `if` on it to either call `.json()` or `.blob()` depending on what you need. An image only example of this is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50248437/1542723

Comment: yeah @Ferrybig, I used the "if" condition on the response headers, based on that I am constructing the logic.